# Spree Routes Not Working after Database Reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I recently had to reset my development database (because of Spree migration complications) and now some of my Spree routes seem to be missing.

I have the following Spree-related gems:

```
gem 'spree', '>= 4.3'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 4.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.6'
```

I have this in my `routes.rb` file as the only spree-specific route...nothing custom:

```
mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/store', as: 'spree'
```

However, when I go to `http://localhost:3000/store` I get an error saying `No route matches [GET] "/store"`.

This is especially strange because when I run `rails routes` the first thing that comes up is:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                       Controller#Action
                                   spree        /store                                                                                            Spree::Core::Engine
```

I have run `rake spree_auth:admin:create` and created (and confirmed) an admin user, if that helps.

Can anyone see why my Spree isn't appearing?